# Error loading sass-rails - can't install simple_form (with or without) bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, simple-form

I'm trying to install simple_form with bootstrap for Rails 4.2.5 Ruby 2.2.3p173. Tried also without the bootstrap and same output

I've read github page for simple_form, bootstrap and sass-rails. Tried some questions and answers here and the same error, so here it goes:

```
>rails generate simple_form:install
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:
in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to l
oad the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.r
b:99:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Francisco/Desktop/RoR/workout_app/config/application.rb:7:
in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I tried different versions of sass-rails, but nothing worked.
The gems:

```
gem 'rails',            '4.2.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails',       '5.0'
gem 'uglifier',         '1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',     '4.1.1'
gem 'haml',             '4.0'
gem 'simple_form',      '3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',   '3.3.6'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do Ruby projects automatically load dependencies of gems declared in your gemfile as well?  I see sass-rails, but I don't see its dependency (sass) listed.

Comment: [The docs says](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#bootstrap) that you have to use `bootstrap` option -> `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`. Maybe thats the issue? Also, did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Tried both forms, same error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (I don't have bootstrap)
I changed the Gemfile to:

```
gem 'sass-rails',       '~> 5.0'
```

Then uninstalled all sass-rails versions and installed again:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass-rails
bundle install
bundle update
```